# Giving the examples of recursive step

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please edit if it is off-topic as I don't know where to put it.

Let  be the subset of ℤ × ℤ defined as:

Basis step:

$• (0, 0) ∈ $

Recursive step: if (, ) ∈ , then:

$• (,  + 1) ∈ $

$• ( + 1,  + 1) ∈ $

$• ( + 2,  + 1) ∈ $

a. List 5 elements of ℤ × ℤ that are in .

b. List 5 elements of ℤ × ℤ that are not in .

c. Make a conjecture about the elements of ; that is, formulate a statement that
  is true for every (,) in . For example: for every (, ) in ,  ≥ 0 and  ≥ 0.

**My attempt->**

a) $(0,1)$,$(1,1)$,$(2,1)$,$(3,2)$,$(3,3)$

b)$(1,0)$,$(2,0)$,$(3,0)$,$(4,0)$,$(5,0)$

c) I don't know how to do this

Please verify mine and correct if there was any worng

Comment: Just as a general strategy, I'd plot out the points that belong to the set $S$, to see if you can find some non-recursive characterization that looks likely.  Is there a region of the plane to which all elements of $S$, and only those elements, belong?

Comment: c) $2b \ge a \ge 0$